# Why these lines of code doesn't run as expected?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, richtextbox

I'm creating a chat application and I want to display names in **Bold** . When the form is first load, I display the History conversation from database on a `RichTextBox` control using these lines of code and i want to display the name in Bold :

Here's all the code to make this possible :

```
string strProvider = "Data Source=" + srv_host + ";Database=" + srv_db + ";User ID=" + srv_user + ";Password=" + srv_pass;
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            string strCmd = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE task_id=@task_id AND ((from_usr=@from AND to_usr=@to) OR (from_usr=@to AND to_usr=@from)) ORDER BY at_time ASC";
            MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(strCmd, myConn);
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("from", frm_usr);
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("to", to_usr);
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("task_id", tid);
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // execute now

            MySqlDataReader dr = myCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + ": " + dr.GetValue(6) + Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = dr.GetValue(1).ToString().Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font,FontStyle.Bold);
            }

            myConn.Dispose();
        }


        catch (Exception E) { MessageBox.Show(E.Message); }
```

And these are the lines of code that doesn't work as expected :

```
 while (dr.Read())
            {
                string text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + ": " + dr.GetValue(6) + Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = dr.GetValue(1).ToString().Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font,FontStyle.Bold);
            }
```

**Edit:**
`dr.GetValue(1).ToString()` Holds tha full name of user 
 `dr.GetValue(6).ToString()` Hold the message
The problem with code above is that it displays only the first name in Bold but other lines are not affected. See the image [image]

Could some one please tell me the reason why the code isn't working. I couldn't figure out where is the error.
Thank-you

Comment: What framework? WPF or Winforms Edit: Nevermind, I see its winforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are having here is that `richTextBox1.SelectionStart` is always zero, meaning that the formatting will only ever be applied to the first line in the text box.

Try setting this to `richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength`.

**Edit:**

Try setting it to

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength - text.Length;
```

**Edit 2:**

I think the Invalid Argument thing is caused by the use of `Environment.NewLine`. If I use instead `"\n"`, the code works fine. The problem is that `Environment.NewLine` is of course `\r\n` on Windows, yet the `richtextBox1` seems to be ignoring the `\r`. This results in `richTextBox1.TextLength - text.Length` being -1 in the first iteration.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got all text in bold except the first line in normal font ??!

Comment: Invalid Argument Value -1 is not valid for 'SelectionStart' Parameter name: SelectionStart

Comment: Your code does Work Correctly when i put a predefined Text from IDE on the richTextBox.. Is there a way to workaround this without adding a Text to the richTextBox @nick_w

Comment: @ShikataGaNai Hmm, it looks like your edit was not accepted. Anyway, see my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test but it may be because the `SelectionStart` index is always 0, try setting it to the start of the line you just added

```
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + ": " + dr.GetValue(6) + Environment.NewLine;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = dr.GetValue(1).ToString().Length;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font,FontStyle.Bold);
        }
```

Comment: doesn't work either :( I got all lines in bold except first one